# How To Get Excel Ribbon Click Event

Tags: c#

I want to Get all the MS Excel Ribbon Click Event Log like

When User click on Ribbon Button in Menu Bar Actions - Copy,Cut,Paste,Text Align in Excel Sheet than i want to get log in text file . where user clicked So that we can track what activity is perform by the user on excel sheet.

so any suggestion how i can achieve this.

Comment: Can you tell us a bit more about what you're trying to achieve. If you're using MS interop, then I don't believe it allows the user to access Ribbons

Comment: Yes I am Using MS interop Library. and i want to achieve all user activity when user work with excel sheet like if user click on Paste Link than i want to get log user clicked on Paste. same way i want all user click action log.

Comment: My understanding is that you can only capture events where the data has changed and not when the user interacts preforms clicks or interacts with ribbon. Heres a VB.net example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/troubleshoot/office-developer/handle-excel-event-using-vb-net. Also I would recommend updating the question so that it's a bit more clearer for other users.